# 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 2273: character maps to <undefined>

Tags: python, lstm, stanford-nlp, sentiment-analysis, word-embedding

I am trying to perform Sentiment analysis and am getting stuck adding a library of words for embedding vectors to help my model convert words into numbers.  I am receiving an error and cannot get past.  Can you please take a look and offer a suggestion to move forward?

```js
import pandas as pd
d213_data = pd.read_csv('D213_Combined_Cleaned.csv')
d213_data

d213_data['Rating'].value_counts()

!pip install wget
import wget
url = 'http://downloads.cs.stanford.edu/nlp/data/glove.6B.zip'
filename = wget.download(url)
print(filename) 

import sys
from zipfile import PyZipFile
for zip_file in sys.argv[1:]:
    pzf = PyZipFile('glove.6B.zip')
    pzf.extractall()

import numpy as np
words = dict()
def add_to_dict(d, filename):
  with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
      line = line.split(' ')
      print(line)
      break
    
      try:
        d[line[0]] = np.array(line[1:], dtype=float)
      except:
        continue

add_to_dict(words, 'glove.6B.50d.txt')
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/344zV.png)

Answer (score 0):

Consider opening or reading your file this way:

```
with open('filename.extension', "r+", encoding="utf-8") as json_data:
  #file.read()
  #file.load()
```